# Question about Horizontal alignment for WPF Image control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

For the WPF Image control, Horizontal alignment doesn't work.. Any ideas? I've pasted the exact code below.. the image appears in the middle..

```
<Canvas Canvas.Top="550" Canvas.Left="225" Width="500" Height="100">
  <Border BorderBrush="#323232" BorderThickness="75" Width="500" Height="100"></Border>
  <Image  Canvas.Left="0" DataContext="...." Source="...." HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="75" Width="275"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

Canvas uses the Left, Right, Top, Bottom settings to place children in a specific pixel location so Alignment settings on children with fixed size have no effect.

Comment: Don't use a Canvas for layout unless you want absolute positioning for all of its children. A Grid is probably more suitable for what you want here.